# Background music is playing twice

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, background-music

When the view gets loaded on my menu (menuViewController) the background music starts (which works). Then when I click start and go to my game (GameViewController) and go back to menu (menuViewController) it starts playing twice.

Here's my viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if x == false{
        setButtons()

        // get path of audio file

        let myFilePathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Background Music Loop (Free to Use)", ofType: "mp3")
        if let myFilePathString = myFilePathString {

            let myFilePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myFilePathString)
            do { try myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: myFilePathURL)
                myAudioPlayer.volume = 0.4
                myAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                myAudioPlayer.play()
                myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried instantiating the menuViewController and then using that instance instead of automatically creating a new one (which i guess didn't work)

This is in my GameViewController

```
@IBAction func goToMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuViewController")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "gameToMenu" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! menuViewController
            destinationController.x = true
    }
```

I also get an error that says:

> "Warning: Attempt to present Ninja.menuViewController: 0x7fdad4cdbf20 on Ninja.GameViewController: 0x7fdad1c1d7a0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: You are presenting view controller on top of view controller,  you need to make sure the parent view controller is dismissing

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ok thanks but I'm a beginner so can you explain me how to do that ?

Comment: There are many ways, just search this site for swapping view controllers,  to check if it is dismissing, in each view controller `override deinit` and `print("ViewControllerName deinit")`  so you know they are being removed

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm using  this code to swap view controllers :               `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)                           let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuViewController") as! menuViewController
        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` but when you said to print( "viewcontrollername deinit")  if it dismisses it didn't work

Comment: Like I said, you are just adding one view controller after another, essentially building a tower of view controllers,  if it didnt work then that means you are not removing the old ones

Comment: @KnightOfDragon Sorry im a beginner so I dont know how to remove the old ones

Comment: @Knight0fDragon i still get this even if it is dismissed `Attempt to present <Ninja.GameViewController: 0x7f9d9a4a13b0> on <Ninja.menuViewController: 0x7f9d9a47ada0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
menuviewcontroller deinit`

Comment: The error  saying you are trying to load GameViewController on top of menuViewController,  but you currently have a different view controller on the screen

Comment: @Knight0fDragon how is that possible i only have 2 view controllers

Comment: you THINK you have 2, but in reality, you keep spawning new ones

Comment: @Knight0fDragon `@IBAction func playGame(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController") as! GameViewController
        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        print("cancel")
        
    }` When i run the app and then press play it goes to the gameviewcontroller and then automatically goes back to my menuviewcontroller. Is this code wrong ?

Comment: if that is line by line then that won't work, you are dismissing your VC on self, then dismissing self, so self and vc no longer are on your view

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so how would you recommend me to write that piece of code ? (sorry for disturbing you so much)

Comment: like i said, i can't help you because there are so many approaches,  but if you are using segues, I wouldn't even bother doing what you are doing, and instead just use them, and unwind them when you are done.